# htaccess - redirect parent folder to file within parent folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to redirect the user to a file within a folder if the user types the folder's address as a URL.

For example:

> https://www.example.com/shop

should redirect to:

> https://www.example.com/shop/en_GB/index.html

I've tried to do it using a htaccess file in the root with the following rule:

```
Redirect 301 /shop    https://www.example.com/shop/en_GB/index.html
```

but this does not work - it adds the file URL over and over again in the address bar.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` directive matches any URI pattern that starts with the given string. Hence you're getting a redirect loop.

You should use `RedirectMatch` directive for this purpose that supports regex and allows you to match precise strings.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/?$ /shop/en_GB/index.html
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing or clear browser cache completely.